# sqldatareader with login(Invalid object name Role)

Tags: c#, authentication, sqldatareader

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    sqlCon.Open();
    String Name = textBox1.Text;
    String password=textBox2.Text;

    SqlCommand check = new SqlCommand("SELECT r.RoleName FROM Role r WHERE RoleID ID(SELECT s.RoleID FROM Tbl_Registration s WHERE UserName=@Name AND Password=@pass)", sqlCon);

    check.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name);
    check.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", password);

    SqlDataReader rd = check.ExecuteReader();
    string Role = "";
    if (rd.HasRows)
    {
        while (rd.Read())
        {
            if (rd["RoleName"] != DBNull.Value)
            {
                Role = rd["RoleName"].ToString();
            }
       }
    }
    if (Role == "Admin")
    {   Ship_Management a = new Ship_Management();
        a.Show();
    }
    else if (Role == "User")
    {
        Ship_Management b = new Ship_Management();
        b.Show();
    }
    else if (Role == "Guest")
    {
        Ship_Management d = new Ship_Management();
        d.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You are not a autorized User");
    }

    sqlCon.Close();
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: SqlDataReader rd = check.ExecuteReader();
    string Role = "";

Comment: Did you forget this question?

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's just a typo. ID -> IN.

```
SqlCommand check = new SqlCommand("SELECT r.RoleName FROM Role r WHERE RoleID IN (SELECT s.RoleID FROM Tbl_Registration s WHERE UserName=@Name AND Password=@pass)", sqlCon);
```